# Calibration error for Sentinel 1 image in SNAP toolbox

Tags: remote-sensing, error, radar, sentinel-1, sentinel-snap

I am working with a Sentinel 1 SLC IW image (VV+VH) and trying to calibrate the data in the SNAP toolbox. However, it keeps returning the error "cannot construct data buffer"

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: This error is likely caused by [insufficient amounts of RAM](http://forum.step.esa.int/t/error-cannot-construct-databuffer/376/24). What are the details of the machine you are running SNAP on?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My computer has 16GB RAM and is a 64-bit operating system. It is built for handling GIS and remote sensing data so this is why I was surprised.

Comment: Can you please include your SNAP configuration? e.g. how many RAM is used by the VM, how many paralell threads, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the error is due to RAM but not the system RAM, the available RAM for SNAP. 
you can change the configuration in the snappy.ini file located in the snappy folder. and increase available RAM 
    Change the line

## java_max_mem: 4G

```
to e.g.
java_max_mem: 6G
A recommended value is 70%-80% of the available RAM in your system.
```

see:
http://forum.step.esa.int/t/increase-snappy-memory-beginner/6269